# Android NavigationDrawerFragment layout appears in the fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout, navigation-drawer

I am programming an application in Android Studio and I decided to use the NavigationDrawerActivity for the main screen activity. Automatically, Android Srudio creates two .java classes (Main.java an NavigationDrawerActivity.java) and three layouts.

My problemis: when I want to put a button in the main screen (where the navigation drawer can be opened, of course), the other Fragments that are accessed from the Navigation Drawer have also the button of the main Activity. I mean, the layout of the main activity doesný dissappear from the fragments!

What can I do?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course the layout of the `Activity` does not disappear! The `Activity` is the container for the `Fragments`, it is not replaced by them. Use the layout of the `Activity` to arrange the `Fragments` and whatever you put in the layout of the `Activity` will be present for any `Fragment` you attach to the `Activity`.

Comment: So, What can I do if I want to customize the layout of the main activity, and when I select a fragment to be started, the layout of the activity dissapear?

Comment: You can't, that is the completely wrong approach. There shouldn't be ui elements in the Activity that are not permanent and shared across all `Fragments`. If you want to change parts of your layout dynamically ensure that everything is in a `Fragment`.